# How to convert regex Python to regex javascript

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I wrote a regex python but I do not find how to convert to be compatible in javascript.

I try with the table comparisons but it does not give me the equivalents or other possibilities.http://web.archive.org/web/20130830063653/http://www.regular-expressions.info:80/refflavors.html

```regex
/^(\[([-\w]+)\])|(^;{0}([\w\.]+)[\s+=\s{0,}]+([\w\-\s\.\"\:\/]+))/gm
```

I try to capture categories with [] , keys before '=' and values after '=' ​​and it looks like that and i used [exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/RegExp/exec)() for php.ini file and exlude all comment ';'  :

```
[exif]
; Exif UNICODE user comments are handled as UCS-2BE/UCS-2LE and JIS as JIS.
; Local Variables:
;zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.20/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/eaccelerator.so"
  eaccelerator.shm_size="16"
  eaccelerator.cache_dir="/Applications/MAMP/tmp/eaccelerator"
  eaccelerator.enable="1"
[xcache-common]

xcache.admin.user = "xcache" ; comment
xcache.readonly_protection = Off
xcache.count =                 1
; just a hash hints, you can always store count(items) > slots
xcache.slots =                8K
;ttl of the cache item, 0=forever
xcache.ttl   = 

[Session]
session.save_path = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php
;         use subdirectories for session storage
;
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=,fieldset="
```

In my case the current regex does not capture a pair of value keys in two.

Comment: It should already work in JavaScript. You can also remove `;{0}` since it's redundant.

Comment: try using: https://regex101.com/ it supports both languages and it will tell you whats wrong

Comment: Not sure `[\s+=\s{0,}]` is what you're looking to do here... You also don't need to escape *everything* `[\w\-\s\.\"\:\/]`

Comment: You might even provide some strings so that we could be of help with the pattern. As it stands, it looks overly complicated.

Comment: Try `/^(\[([-\w]+)\])|^([\w.]+)(?:\s*=[^\S\r\n]*("[^"]*"|\S+))?/g`, see https://regex101.com/r/KNmReq/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you, it works but I also have a pair of value and keys like this:

 ```
  eaccelerator.compress_level="9"
  eaccelerator.allowed_admin_path="/Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp"
```

Comment: And it works - https://regex101.com/r/KNmReq/2